# Azure CDN Rule Engine

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, rule-engine, url-rewrite-module, azure-cdn

I host and html site in Azure CDN (under a with Premier paid Plan) so it gives me a Rules engine, which gives a lots of features to control the flow. I would like to have **URL redirect** and **URL rewrite** Azure CDN rules, please.

#### Example:

Given a site like `www.example.com` on which users can access see info as `www.example.com/username`, I've setup the following rules in IIS:

```
<rule name="rulex" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
</rule>
```

So, how I can set the same rule in Azure CDN please? Is this possible? Any links to examples would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The following official documentation from microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine) explains the same

Answer (score -3):

Azure CDN does not support URL Rewriting. It simply caches the URL requested (according to any query string or header caching rules set) and returns the cached response for subsequent requests for the same URL.

Comment: OP clearly said " Azure CDN (under a with Premier paid Plan) so it gives me a Rules engine" so it does allow URL Rewriting and Redirect. Azure CDN with Verizon P1 plan does allow URL Rewriting.